# How to disable java out-of-date ActiveX control blocking feature in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, activex, internet-explorer-10

Recently IE has introduced a new security feature **Out of date Activex blocking**. 
If your application uses any Activex control. And while loading it in IE it checks whether it is up to date or not.
 If its not, it prompts with a message and blocks the loading.
For example, If your system contains lesser version of jre (assume 1.7.0_55) and if you try to load an applet in IE. it prompts like this
[image: Java Activex prompt]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC744119.png))</sub>

because there is an update for java is available.


Is there any way to disable this feature. I checked following link from microsoft,
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn761713.aspx

 They have given two solutions for this problem

 1. Modifying Group policy settings using Administrative templates

 2. Modifying Group policy settings using registry commands

 These solutions are system level and more confusing for the user. Is there any simple and better solution.

Answer (score 8):

This security block wont work in trusted sites zone. So to disable this feature add the site to the **trusted sites** and put the security level as medium. 
If it still blocking, delete the browser cache and load it again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [original blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/06/internet-explorer-begins-blocking-out-of-date-activex-controls.aspx) by the IE dev team or the [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2991000)?

They seem pretty definitive when combined with the information in the TechNet article you linked to.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score 1):

From the link posted by [Lance Leonard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538158/lance-leonard)

> This feature can be turned off by using the policy “Turn off blocking
>   of outdated ActiveX controls for Internet Explorer.” This might be
>   used temporarily in combination with logging, to assess ActiveX
>   controls before re-enabling the feature. This can also be enabled,
>   like all four policies, with a registry key—in this case, a REG_DWORD
>   “HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext\VersionCheckEnabled"
>   with value of zero.

Neither of the options provided are system/workstation level changes - both can be managed using Group Policy Administrative templates, or by using Group Policy Preferences.

You can also implement these changes via PowerShell, but I'd recommend that you use Group Policy to provide administrative transparency for your support staff.